# chart.js aspect ratio not square

Tags: chart.js

I am trying to draw a line graph but I require the x and y axis to be square in a ratio of y units 2 to x units 1

In other words

the unit reading 2 on the y axis should be equal distance to reading of 1 on the x axis

I have set my canvas to be 100% on width and height

and I have the following

```
ticks: {
  beginAtZero: true,
  scaleStepWidth:1,
  stepSize: 1,
  scaleSteps:7,
  steps: 7

}

and

ticks: {
  beginAtZero: true,
  scaleStepWidth:1,
  stepSize: 1,
  scaleSteps:14,
  steps: 14

}
```

Amongst many other attempts but none of which seem to make a difference

Here is my graph

[image]

The "square" of measure of 1 on the y axis versus 0.5 on the x axis measures 4.9cm on the y and 4.6cm on the x and I am trying to get it to be exact square

[image]

Can anyone help with this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem where I needed to maintain a 1:1 ratio, and finally solved it by making the length of the x and y-axis equal:

```
      // Make the length of the x and y-axis equal
      const xLength = totalXMax - totalXMin;
      const yLength = totalYMax - totalYMin;
      if (xLength > yLength) {
        const difference = xLength - yLength;
        totalYMax = totalYMax + difference / 2;
        totalYMin = totalYMin - difference / 2;
      } else {
        const difference = yLength - xLength;
        totalXMax = totalXMax + difference / 2;
        totalXMin = totalXMin - difference / 2;
      }

      // Set the new min and max on the chart instance
      instance.chart.options.scales.xAxes[0].ticks.min = totalXMin;
      instance.chart.options.scales.xAxes[0].ticks.max = totalXMax;
      instance.chart.options.scales.yAxes[0].ticks.min = totalYMin;
      instance.chart.options.scales.yAxes[0].ticks.max = totalYMax;
```

To keep the chart square even when a user resizes the window, add these options to your chart config:

```
        ...
        maintainAspectRatio: true,
        aspectRatio: 1,
        ...
```

For a 2:1 ratio, set `aspectRatio` to 2. See https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/general/responsive.html